# DB returns string instead of int (mysqlnd for PHP-7.1 / Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, debian, mysqlnd, php-7.1

A few days ago, [I asked a question about a bug I found in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791557/php-laravel-type-of-var-is-different-from-local-to-server).

To fix it, I installed php5-mysqlnd on my server.

Today, I upgraded my application to the latest php 7.1.*. Everything works correctly, except the bug is back again, i.e. integers in the database are returned as strings, which fails my strict comparison.

I tried to find a package for mysqlnd for php 7.1 but there are none (yet?). But mysqlnd seems enabled though...

**phpinfo()**

```
PHP Version => 7.1.3-2+0~20170315222009.20+jessie~1.gbpc7e7dd
System => Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64

mysqlnd
mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b396954eeb2d1d9ed7902b8bae237b287f21ad9e $

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b396954eeb2d1d9ed7902b8bae237b287f21ad9e $
```

Output on localhost:

> "id" => 5

**Output on server:**

> "id" => "5"

1/ Is there something else I should look?

2/ In general, should I refactor my code to accept strings from the db instead of expecting ints?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO` for your query?

Comment: @TomUdding I'm using Laravel 5.4 with PDO.

Comment: What data type you've used for `id` field in your table?

Comment: @TheAlpha In Laravel migrations, `$table->increments('id')` which is an unsigned int in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh, I'm dumb! At least I learned something today.

The phpinfo() came from the php version of the console, not Apache.
Turns out php7.1 and mysqlnd was not loaded in Apache.

Everything is fine now...