# Laravel API response return double quoted numeric value

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Laravel Version: 5.6.12
PHP Version: 7.1
Vuejs Version: 2.5
Database Driver & Version: MySQL 5.7 (Using mysqlnd driver)

**Description**:
API response returning double quoted numeric value therefore producing undesired output. The response recieved from the server is attached in this image:

[Resonse from Laravel API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvmkm.jpg)

```
$data = ['message' => 'Hello'];
return response()->json($data, 200);
```

Why numeric values in response is double quoted?

Resolved:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-api-response-return-double-quoted-numeric-value

Comment: Add code that generates the response, as requested on the [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23679) you created.

Comment: Yes add the code so we can check.

Comment: It is simple response()->json() return  code. Please check now.

Comment: where the data from, eloquent model?

Comment: Did you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42862620/4848587

Comment: I think you have saved values as string replace your data line with this and check again  $data = ['message' => 'Hello', 'testValue' => 100];

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got the solution. It is in laracasts link I have shared.

Comment: *In addition to returning strings from your routes and controllers, you may also return arrays. The framework will automatically convert the array into a JSON response* from [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#creating-responses).